# Brother Printer works as a printer but not as a scanner

Tags: big-sur, printing, scanning

The original question applied to printer model Brother HL-2280DW on Big Sur. But the question (and answer!) apply to other Brother printer models and other MacOS versions.

Is there a way to get the scanner functionality to work?  As a printer it works without any extra drivers needed (just click "add printer" and it works with "generic PCL printer").  The [drivers](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2280dw_us&_ga=2.149310399.820654352.1631829058-1285467650.1631829058) say they only support 10.15?

Comment: [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/) suppors a lot of "old" scanners

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. For me it was the Brother Printer HL-L2380DW on Monterey, but the behavior was the same. I could delete and re-add the printer with no problem. It would print, but it would not scan. Other computers on the same network could scan as expected. So it was clearly a computer issue, not a printer issue. Also, Brother's iPrint&Scan application is installed and current. But it cannot scan either.

One weird detail was that scanning worked at some point in the distant past. Then it stopped working. I don't scan often, so I'm not sure when it stopped. Perhaps when upgrading to Big Sur... but that's not certain. Upgrading from Big Sur to Monterey did not hurt, and it provided an updated driver... but it didn't give me the ability to scan. Another weird detail: Scanning via USB works. This is impractical for me, but it definitely works as a workaround.

@rogerdpack says that deleting and re-adding the printer helped, but that wasn't the case for me. He also mentions "Scanner Driver (ICA)" driver, but without any instructions (or any verb!). He's correct that this is the key. I will elaborate with more precision.

For me the solution was:

- Download the Scanner Driver (ICA) (I used [HL-L2380DW drivers](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2380dw_us_as&os=10072), but the same concept applies to other models.)
- Install the Scanner Driver (ICA)
- FYI: notice that the driver gets installed here:

  /Library/Image Capture/Devices/Brother Scanner.app/
- Uninstall the printer
- Reinstall the printer
- FYI: Reinstalling looks exactly like before. But now it includes Print **AND** Scan. Hooray!
- FYI: Attempt to use the scanner. It fails. Repeat several times, and it fails each time.
- FYI: Attempt to scan using the Mac "Image Capture" utility. It fails.
- Attempt to scan using Brother's iPrint&Scan application. I hate this app. It used to not work, but now it works. Hooray?
  EDIT: based on comments it appears that **rebooting** could take the place of using iPrint&Scan for this step.
- Attempt to use the scanner. It succeeds. Hooray!!

It's not at all clear why I had to run iPrint&Scan. Perhaps this is a red herring, and perhaps that's not truly required. But it really seemed like it was.

My end result is that basic scanning works exactly as intended from the Mac Printers & Scanners menu. But it was a lot of work and a lot of trial and error to get there.

Comment: Just a thank you and informing that it worked on macOS Monterey with a MFC-9330CDW. It was only detected as a printer and now, after installation of ICA drivers above, it's seen by Image Capture!

Comment: Same problem here with an HL-2280DW that had been working fine on my previous computer running Catalina. I was able to get it to work without running iPrint&Scan, but I had to reboot my Mac between uninstalling the printer and reinstalling it. No idea what really fixed it, but now I can print and scan. Yay!

Comment: It's good to know that running iPrint&Scan wasn't needed. Perhaps if I had slipped a reboot into my steps somewhere I could have avoided iPrint&Scan. I remain vaguely curious... though now that things work well I'm not likely to investigate further.

Comment: Yes, can confirm reboot after installing ICA driver brought back the Scan tab and Image Capture scanning on my MFC-9340CDW.

Comment: Thanks for the recipe, this also worked for brother DCP9022-CDW and macOS Ventura 13.0.1. Like @ScottG I only performed a reboot and did not need iPrint & Scan.

Comment: To add another data point for my MacBook Pro M1 on Ventura 13.0.1; the steps work up until the scan option appearing but failing after drive installation. Further steps don't work, regardless of if I reboot or install iPrint&Scan. Can't get the scanner to work at all on my M1.

Comment: This worked for me for my new computer on Ventura. I remember having to do a similar procedure before by downloaind the Scanner Driver (ICA) and then reiinstalling the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems if I installed the 10.15 driver "regardless" then deleted and re-added the printer, both scanning and printing show up now.  I installed the "Scanner Driver (ICA)" driver.  Seems from the comments and other answer this is needed, but not enough.

My macbook then gave the message "You do not have permission to open the application “Brother Scanner”. Contact your computer or network administrator for assistance."  Based on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253019354 I downloaded iprint&scan and it is working now.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as it seems you don't know if what you propose would work or not and it seems to lead to another error. And avoid asking for upvotes as well. For information, iprint&scan only isn't enough. ICA driver is needed.

Comment: OK I added  that both are needed, thanks for the comment, cheers!